# Unable to Connect to VPN via OpenWrt/Wireguard on WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, vpn, openwrt, wireguard

I am having issues connecting via WireGuard on OpenWRT wirelessly.

I have followed ALL instructions on [AzireVPN's website](https://www.azirevpn.com/support/guides/router/openwrt/wireguard) except for Firewall Zones settings, which I had to set as follows for it to work (it wouldn't work at all with their settings, not even via Ethernet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdCk1.png

Now, here's what I have for my wireless settings, maybe you can shed some light so I can get this to work via WiFi:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrSCn.png

Please note under Interface Configuration > Network there is no wg interface to choose from, I am unsure if this has anything to do with the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUubA.png

Another bit of crucial information, my current (physical) network setup is as follows:

- Main DSL line connected to ISP router/modem
- OpenWRT router with WireGuard VPN installed connected via WAN to ISP
  router in ETH0 port.
- As you can see on one of the screenshots above, OpenWRT router's Mode
  is Access Point, ISP Modem/Router has DHCP activated.

As highlighted above, the issue is I am unable to get this to work via WiFi, it works via Ethernet when connected to OpenWRT router though.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

so I've been struggling with this very same issue, I tried several guides and whatnot to do this, probably this is due to the fact that I'm quite an stranger to networking, anyway it turns out I overlooked the fact that curl and ca-bundle need to be installed, after that the connection was routed through wireguard.